# How do i display plugin shortcode as a text in my post?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

few days I made a free plugin and I want to shortcode to my website as a text for visitor help. Could anybody tell me is there any wp plugin or any functions to show shortcode show as a text in post content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use double square brackets for it.

**For example :**

if the shortcode is like `[my_short_code 1]`

then to show it as it is, you can add it as like `[[my_short_code 1]]`

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Actually Jenis, I want to show my plugin shortcode as a text in my website for visitor help and they can easily get plugin style shortcode. here I am giving the image and live link. img link: http://prntscr.com/764smx Live Example website: http://perfectpointmarketing.com/plugins/ppm-accordion-updated/

Answer (score 0):

try this 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/

this is a plugin that creates a shortcode for you

or this
https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-generator/

Comment: Actually Jenis, I want to show my plugin shortcode as a text in my website for visitor help and they can easily get plugin style shortcode.     here I am giving the image and live link. img link: [link] (http://prntscr.com/764smx)
Example website: http://perfectpointmarketing.com/plugins/ppm-accordion-updated/